# How to send the mp3/mp4 file from Raw folder to server on Android?

Tags: java, android, file-io

I have the mp3/mp4 files on Raw folder. I need to send these files to server side. I'm using `MultipartRequestEntity` (`FilePart`) for sending the files to server side. How to get the Raw folder files as `FILE`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to read from that file using something like

```
InputStream instream = this.getResources.openRawResource(R.raw.myfile);
```

and then just read your standard input stream (I suggest wrapping it with buffering, e.g. `BurreredInputReader`)